# sending serial data from Android to a com port on PC through local network

Tags: arduino, local-network

Hi I have an Arduino connected to a PC with USB and I'm sharing that port on my local network with a USB network gate

I don't have any background in networking and I'm pretty new to Arduino

I'm using Arduino Mega 2560

Now I want to send data from my Android device to my Arduino through my local network (wifi connection) the Arduino does not have an Ethernet shield